# Resolution of vectors along different directions

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, vectors

I have a small doubt regarding the resolution of forces and vectors.

Suppose, we have our standard cartesian coordinate system, with unit vectors $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$. Now we have defined polar coordinates with the unit vectors $\hat{r}$ and $\hat{\theta}$.
Suppose, we have a vector $\vec{r} = r\hat{r}$. We can write it as $r cos\theta \hat{i} + r sin\theta \hat{j} $. Thus we have managed to find the components of the vector along the $x$ and $y$ directions. Thus, if we had a force, we could find its components along $x$ and $y$ in the same fashion.

However, what if the force or the vector was initially along the $x$ direction, say $\vec{x}=x\hat{i}$. What would be the component of this vector along $\hat{r}$ ? Suppose, this vector represented Force. What would be the component of this force along $\hat{r}$

The first case is like, the wind is blowing towards the north east, finds its component along north and east. However, the second case is like, what if the wind was blowing east in the first place ? How will I find its component along the north east. Do I do the exact same thing and multiply by $cos\theta$ or should I multiply by $sec\theta$ for this second case ?

What I know is, if the original force was acting along $\hat{r}$, and we were given it's x-component, we would have multiplied with $sec\theta$ to get back the original force. However, what if the original force was blowing along the x direction, then what ? Since $r=xsec\theta$, should we multiply $sec\theta$ ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have identified is a very common situation. In physics we rarely deal with just vectors. More common is to deal with vector fields, i.e. a vector, possibly different one, in each point in space.

A good way to resolve this is to note that $\mathbf{\hat{x}}=\boldsymbol{\nabla}x$ (check it).

So if your force is $\mathbf{F}=x\mathbf{\hat{x}}$, then simply do:

$$
\mathbf{F}=x\mathbf{\hat{x}}=x\,\boldsymbol{\nabla}x=\left(r\cos\theta\right)\boldsymbol{\nabla}\left(r\cos\theta\right)=\left(r\cos\theta\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{\hat{r}}\partial_r + \frac{1}{r}\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}\partial_\theta \right)\left(r\cos\theta\right)=\left(r\cos\theta\right)\cdot\left(\cos\theta\,\mathbf{\hat{r}}-\sin\theta \,\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}} \right)
$$

Where I have evaluated 2d gradient in cylindrical coordinates

So the component of force along $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ direction in case of $\mathbf{F}=x\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ will be:

$$
\mathbf{\hat{r}}.\mathbf{F}=r\cos^2\theta 
$$

---

ADDENDUM

Of course if you "know" that $\mathbf{\hat{x}}=\cos\theta \,\mathbf{\hat{r}}-\sin\theta \, \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$ you can bypass the manipulations with the gradient and deriviatives and simply substitute $x\to r\cos\theta$ and $\mathbf{\hat{x}}\to \dots$

Comment: Ah so, we can say $\hat{r}.F = rcos^2\theta = xcos\theta$, right ? The rules of resolution remains the same. If the force is along $\hat{r}$, we multiply the magnitude with $cos\theta$ and $sin\theta$ to get out x and y components. But in general, if we have a force along a direction $\hat{a}$ and we want to figure out its component along a direction $\hat{b}$, we just multiply the magnitude with the cosine of the angle between them, from the definition of the scalar product. Am I right ?

Comment: Shouldn't you get $r$ and $\theta$ as a function of $x$ and $y$? I think you are going the complicated way for a simple thing.

Comment: @NakshatraGangopadhay, there is nothing wrong with what you said, but I would be a bit more cautious. In general you will have the vector field you care about $\mathbf{F}$ and the vector field that you want to project onto, e.g. $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$. Both of these fields can have expressions that depend on the coordinates of the point at which you are evaluating. What you do then is use scalar product to project $\mathbf{F}$ onto $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$. I think cosine of the angle between them here is a dictraction...

Comment: ... Because here it simply happens to be a nice expression that is connected to the underlying coordinates. Imagine having a 'radial' force from a point that is not at the origin, and then trying to find the radial component of that force relative to the origin. Cosine of the angle between $\mathbf{\hat{r}}$ and $\mathbf{F}$ would not be a nice expression in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ in that case. So be careful :-)

Comment: @GiorgioP, not sure how expressing $r$a and $\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ helps here. I think you want to do it in the opposite direction as my treatment demonstrates. It is a tad more complicated than I was taught, but ...god... I wish I was taught this way rather than relying solely on diagrams or complex number analogies. Diagrams are nice, but not very reliable. The derivative-based approach is much more robust and omni-applicable.

Comment: Your final formula for ${\bf \hat x \cdot F}$ is not consistent with your last formula for $\bf \hat x$. There is no power $2$ of the $\cos \theta$.

Comment: @GiorgioP , are we talking about different things? I gave expression for $\mathbf{\hat{r}}\cdot x\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ not $\mathbf{\hat{x}}\cdot\dots$

Comment: *"Of course if you "know"..."*. Isn't there an expression for $\bf \hat x$?

Comment: @GiorgioP. Well it would be natural to define $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ as normalized ccordinate basis for Cartesian ccordinates, but it tells you nothing about cyllindrical basis vectors and how the two relate. I have done it enough times to know how they relate, or to be able to construct a diagram in my head, and proceed. Suppose you did not know this, what would you do? You could draw diagrams or take few derivatives from the functions that map Cartesian to Cyllindrical coordinates. These days I would prefer the latter

Answer (score 0):

I think that reference to polar coordinates is highly misleading in the present context and reference to vector fields obfuscates the issue. Just referring to the example, the situation is clear and does not require reference to polar coordinates. It is just a matter of projecting vectors.

In the first case, you have a vector $\vec r = r \hat r$, where $\hat r$ is a unit vector pointing in an arbitrary direction in the plane. If $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ are two orthogonal unit vectors of the plane and assuming that the angle between $\hat r$ and $ \hat i$ is $\theta$, $\hat r \cdot \hat i = \cos \theta$ and the component of $\vec r$ along $\hat i$ is $r \cos \theta$.

In the second case, we start with a vector $\vec x =x \hat i$. the component of such a vector in the direction of $\hat r$ is simply $\vec x \cdot \hat r= x \cos \theta $.